# Can Ipad 4 bought in USA work with other mobile operators in Europe?

Tags: ipad

I need information and explanations how Ipad 4 with mobile card can work in Europe
(Alcatel,, Wodafone or others)? Can somebody help me and explain what and how I can change its settings in order to work with the local providers?

Answer (score 1):

In general, yes. Apple has a very easy to read page listing all the LTE channels each iPad supports.

http://www.apple.com/ipad/LTE/

Since no iPad is locked to a carrier, you don't have to jailbreak or unlock them - just pop in the Sim card for whatever carrier you like and you'll be pretty much ready to go. You should also check the non-LTE radio frequencies for each model by looking over the technical specifications page.

http://www.apple.com/ipad/specs/

In the US, the Verizon & Sprint models also speak CDMA as well as operate on all the typical GSM data frequencies - so you might prefer a pure GSM model or one that can work on CDMA if needed, but this won't make much difference for many that want to use an iPad in Europe.

Comment: In addition, most of Europe is running GSM so if you go for that model, you can use local mobile cards from those countries. LTE coverage is not great as yet so if you are outside of major centres, it is useful to have the GSM 3G as very usable backup option.